# How to keep range values in database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

To check a patient's status in a medical test(high, low, average), I have to keep range values for the tests in a table

For a test there can be several ranges.

```
| range     | status  |
|-----------|---------|
| 0 - 100   | Low     |
| 101- 200  | Average |
| 201 - 300 | High    |
```

For another test, ranges can be different according to the gender

```
| range     | Gender | status  |
|-----------|--------|---------|
| 0 - 100   | Male   | Low     |
| 0 - 105   | Female | Low     |
| 100- 200  | Male   | Average |
| 105 - 210 | Female | Average |
| 200 - 300 | Male   | High    |
| 210 - 300 | Female | High    |
```

There can be range data as age, gender, status as well.

How can I map the ranges in database which enables to check which range user is in for a given test result. As an example For a Sugar Test a male user may have a result 45. I need whether the test value is high, low or average.

My initial table solution is shown below. I don't think this is a good solution.

```
| test | min_age | max_age | range_upper | range_lower | Gender | status  |
|------|---------|---------|-------------|-------------|--------|---------|
| 1    | 1       | 10      | 0           | 100         | Male   | Low     |
| 1    | 1       | 10      | 100         | 200         | Male   | Average |
| 1    | 1       | 10      | 200         | 300         | Male   | High    |
| 1    | 1       | 10      | 0           | 100         | Female | Low     |
| 1    | 1       | 10      | 100         | 200         | Female | Average |
| 1    | 1       | 10      | 200         | 300         | Female | High    |
```

Please sorry for my English.

Comment: I would have a table for age bands and a table for what constitutes low, average, etc. for each genderm for each band

Comment: Is it possible to have decimal values in result? If the result were 100.5, does it belong to 0-100 or 101-200? What about 100.0?

Comment: @SalmanA there can be such results. 100.5 is belong to 0-101. my bad. Its a type

Comment: @Strawberry like in sergo's answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59072631/7483684

Comment: not quite; correct on the range reference part, but the status and range reference would be in a separate table from range min and range max

Comment: @Strawberry can you provide an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do not use range reference instead of pair of values?

Table `status_ranges`

```
| id | range_min | range_max | status  |
|----|-----------|-----------|---------|
|  1 |         0 |       100 | Low     |
|  2 |       101 |       200 | Average |
|  3 |       201 |       300 | High    |
```

Table of `tests`

```
| test | value_1 | gender | id_status_of_value_1 | . . . 
|------|---------|--------|----------------------|-----
| 1    |      10 |  Male  |                   1  | . . .
| 1    |     120 |  Male  |                   2  |
| 1    |     235 |  Male  |                   3  |
| . . .
```

Comment: does value_1 means the result of the test?

Comment: @camille yes it does

Comment: How to get the relevant range_min and range_max with the status when a result is given?

Comment: @camille suppose result is in the variable `@result`
`SELECT id FROM status_ranges WHERE @result BETWEEN range_min AND range_max`
Or if result is already set in the main table `tests` then update it with `id` of corresponding range
`UPDATE tests 
SET id_status_of_value1 = (SELECT id FROM status_ranges WHERE tests.result BETWEEN range_min AND range_max)
WHERE test = 1`